# Meteor Local Collection publish/subscribe

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor, and I am trying to use a Local Collection to store some data from an API call without storing it in the DB.
Is there a way to not render the template before the local collection is populated/ready? Is it possible to use publish/subscribe on local collections?

I am using the Packery jQuery plugin to organize this data in a grid, but it doesn't seem to work since I believe the data isn't ready when the code runs.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can't use publish/subscribe on local collections, nor should you need to.

Comment: So is there a way to prevent the template from rendering before the Collection is ready?